# Function of two variables as a product of functions of one variable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, trigonometry

I have tried to write the following function of two variables:

$f(x,t)= \frac{\cos (ax)\cos (at)}{a_1}-\frac{\cos (bx)\cos (bt)}{a_2}$

as a product of two functions of one variable, i.e., $f(x,t)=f_1(x)f_2(t)$.

I appreciate it if you have an idea of who $f_1$ and $f_2$ would be, or if there is any reason why it is not possible to write it like this.

I used the double angle trigonometric formulas without getting good results.

Comment: You can try by writing $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2$. But, it seems not possible to factorize it in that way.

Comment: If $f_1(x_0)=0$ then $f(x_0,t)=0$ for all $t$. Doesn't that suggest that this type of factorization is not possible?

Comment: I did not specify it, you are right, but in principle $a=a_n$ and $b=b_n$ are sequences, so that argument would not be enough

Comment: I think that if it is written in the form of exponentials, it is not possible.

Comment: Would writing $f = f_{1}f_{2} \implies \partial_{x} f = \partial_{x} f_{1} f_{2} \implies f_{1} = c_{1}e^{ \int \frac{\partial_{x} f}{f} \,\mathrm{d} x}$ and noting the antiderivative doesn't exist be of any help?